# Setting up a dns server with a virtualbox vm running Ubuntu and making it accessible via vlans

Tags: virtual-machines, vlan, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

I have a virtual box vm I want to use as a dns server for my local network. I have a few vlans setup. The vm host is 10.0.50.2 The vm is 10.0.50.4

I want to keep everyone out of the 10.0.50.4 network but I do want to make the vm available across my vlans for dns resolution.

I realize I can add a nic and put the vlan on the main network without an issue but I'd like to figure out how to do this with vlans.

I can't find a place in virtualbox to set the default vlan for the vm. So I was thinking I would add the vlans in netplan and then make the vm accessible from all the vlans. Is there a better way? How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a place to do this in virtualbox, so I added a new nic and put it on the main network and then opened up firewall access on port 53 for that box.